# Hiding all elements inside a div except clicked label to show div in the background

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two divs. dvMapContainer works as a full page background and displays a leaflet map, dvEditContainer overlays a div with some controls on top of the map.

Code is like this:

```
<div id="dvMapContainer" style="height: 93%; width: 100%;position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;"></div>

<div class="container" id="dvEditContainer">
    <div class="container-header">Update Inventory</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="plateNumber" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Plate #:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <input type="text"
                   data-ng-model="bb.plateNumber"
                   name="plateNumber"
                   id="plateNumber"
                   class="form-control"/>
        </div>
    </div> 
 </div>
```

What I want to happen is when a user clicks on the label "Plate #" it will hide the entire dvEditContainer, but show the label as it was. When the user clicks on the label again, the dvEditContainer will be visible again.

My jquery code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('label').click(function (e) {
                var target = $(e.target);
                console.log(target);
                $('#dvEditContainer').hide();
                $(target).show();
            });
        });
```

This however hides dvEditContainer as expected but doesnt display the label either.

Any ideas or hints would be much appreciated.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pe5xU/136/) of the non working code.

Comment: you will have to take your label outside the `EditContainer` div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the label is inside a div which is inside the dvEditContainer div, it is hidden as well.

Move the form-group div outside of dvEditContainer.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. as others have pointed out, hiding the parent hides the children as well. Is there a workaround to this where I can keep showing the clicked element without altering the html itself ?

Comment: What about setting the background to a transparent color? `$('#dvEditContainer').css("background", "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)");`

Comment: that is what I am doing now. adding a class with a clear background color. Then I can proceed to hide all elements inside that div except the clicked element. The only problem with this approach is I am not able to move the map under the div.

Answer (score 1):

your `<label>` isn't visible because you just hid its parent.  Either leave `dvEditContainer` visible and hide all elements except your `<label>`, or move your `<label>` to a different parent.

Comment: thank you for the response. Is it possible to move to a different parent temporarily and preserve the position of the label ?